# Visualize gradient on a line at runtime

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm trying to create a Tline Shape at runtime and assign a gradient without success. When creating other shapes such as circles or squares, no problem appears.

Note: At design time, a Tline shape does the gradient. I'm using Tokyo version 10.2

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Objects;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate (Sender: TObject);
var
  DLine     : TLine;
begin
  DLine := Tline.Create (nil);
  DLine.Position.x := 100;
  DLine.Position.y := 100;
  DLine.Height := 300;
  DLine.LineType := TLineType.Left;
  DLine.Stroke.Thickness := 3;
  DLine.Fill.Gradient.Color :=   $FF0000FF; // Blue
  DLine.Fill.Gradient.Color1 :=  $FFFF7F50; // Coral
  DLine.Fill.Kind := TBrushKind.Gradient;
  DLine.Fill.Gradient.Style := TGradientStyle.Linear;
  DLine.Parent := Form1;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Gradient of anything is usually between two values.

Comment: What happens when you change around `DLine.Fill.Gradient.Style`? I'm not familiar with this, but I'm guessing this controls the direction of the gradient, and it could be edge to edge instead of end to end.

Comment: You set `DLine.Height`, but not `DLine.Width`. Is it wide enough to allow space for the gradient to be drawn? `TGradientStyle.Linear` sounds to me like it would paint the gradient from left to right.

Comment: A Line is usually drawn with Pen, not Brush, certainly in VCL but not sure about Firemonkey. - I assume it is the same. Should you not be using a very thin rectangle, rather than a line?

Comment: Thank you all for your help and ideas. The option of the rectangle also served as an alternative solution in practice. Finally, Dmitriy Nekrasov has provided the correct solution with code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]
Use DLine.Stroke instead of DLine.Fill

```
  ...   
  DLine.Stroke.Thickness := 3;
  DLine.Stroke.Gradient.Color :=   $FF0000FF; // Blue
  DLine.Stroke.Gradient.Color1 :=  $FFFF7F50; // Coral
  DLine.Stroke.Kind := TBrushKind.Gradient;
  DLine.Stroke.Gradient.Style := TGradientStyle.Linear;
  ...
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much for the code example.